# Почему у меня не отображается TGrid в FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Всем привет. У меня есть форма FireMonkey, на которой есть TGrid. Я связал его с ADOQuery, чтобы какие то данные на нем видеть, но при компиляции сам TGrid почему то не рендериться и я не могу понять почему. Может вы мне подскажите как решить такую проблему?

PS: Компонент я вообще нигде не изменял, просто перенес его на форму и связал через LiveBindings с ADOQuery. Но что связанный с ADOQuery, что без связи компонент все равно не отображается. И с TStringGrid такая же история.

PSS: *Может это поможет*, но у меня на форме очень много компонентов. 216 если быть точным. Может в этом проблема...